# App.config transformation issue

Tags: app-config

I have implemented App.Config transformation for one of my class library projects, when I am trying to read a key value from my app.config by debugging the Unit test project, it is reading the key value from App.debug.config instead of app.config. Please help me out in this regard.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, as you stated, you are *debugging* your application.

I suppose the XDT sees your current configuration as 'debug' and transforms the proper app.debug.config into app.config.

So, if i understand your question fully, there are two (mostly not helping) answers:
- Remove or disable XDT transformations on your class library.
- Move the proper keys from *app.config* to *app.debug.config* and use the XDT's 'find-and-replace' technique:

`<add name="YOURKEYHERE"xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />`